# What's the probability that number drawn on ball will match number of current draw?

Tags: probability

**There's 5 balls in urn, they have numbers from 1 to 5 on them. We draw 1 ball each time with replacement. What's the probability that number drawn on ball will match number of current draw?**

So I just have to calculate probability of any number matching current draw count, right?
(Third draw, randomed ball has '3' on it)

(Maybe this task could be interpreted as getting '1' ball on first draw, '2' ball on second draw etc)

$$\omega = 5^{5}$$
$$P(A)= \frac{\frac{1}{5}}{5^{5}}$$

Is this variation with repetitions?

Comment: "*What's the probability that number drawn on ball will match number of current draw*"  For *which* draw?  For all draws?  For at least one draw?  For a specific draw?

Comment: @RossMillikan "*with return*" is surely meant to have the same meaning as "*with replacement*"

Comment: I am pretty sure logic wasn't lost after I translated it. Might be mistake by professor?

Comment: So... if you are asking what the probability that very specifically the first ball drawn is $1$ and you don't care about any of the other balls, (*So acceptable sequences include $11213,~12345,~15243,\dots$ and unacceptable include $22345, 25431,\dots$*) this occurs with probability $\frac{1}{5}$, or equivalently written, $\frac{1\times 5^4}{5^5}$.  The same is true if you were to replace $1$ with any other position.  If you want the correct ball for *every* draw, then the only acceptable sequence is $12345$.  This occurs with probability $\frac{1}{5^5}$ (*not $\frac{1/5}{5^5}$*).

Comment: If you want the correct ball for at least one of the draws (*so acceptable sequences include $12345, 15432, 12555, 22222, \dots$ and unacceptable sequences include $54123, 55554, 23452,\dots$*), it is easier to count the unacceptable sequences first.  There are $4^5$ unacceptable sequences (*as in each position there are four available numbers different than the position's number itself*), giving the probability of at least one correct number as $1-\frac{4^5}{5^5}$

Comment: @JMoravitz
Thank you, I might have to email my professor and ask him which version he meant. 
Also is case $\frac{1}{5^{5}}$ variation with repetitions? (I am still not good at telling variations, combinations etc. apart)

Comment: I dislike blindly giving names to things as it often suggests to students to not try to think for themselves and instead try to refer to a formula sheet.  Stop and understand where the formulas on such a formula sheet originally come from and how you could have discovered those formulas yourself.  For this, it is a routine application of the rule of product.  If you insist on calling it something, I have heard "permutations with repetition" however I hate that name as these are not actually permutations.  I have heard "variations" in passing, but we would not call it that where I'm from.

Comment: I would simply call these objects you are counting "*sequences of length five with repetition allowed*"

Comment: @JMoravitz Unfortunately that's guaranteed part of my next exam. We have to decide for each task if its permutation, variation, combination (with/without repetitions)